# Cant click when I do a transform:translate (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, transform

I want auto-adjust and auto-center a div of one game that I am working (HTML5), I have tried some css combinations, the perfect combination is it:

```
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This centers the game great on all moment, but I cant click after use the "centered" class, I dont know whats the problem and its difficult find a solution searching on the net, anybody can help me with this?

The main .html file (with style and js) is there:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- Set the title bar of the page -->
    <title></title>

    <!-- Set the background colour of the document -->
    <style>
        body {
          background: #000000;
          color:#cccccc;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          border: 0px;
        }
        canvas {
                  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
                  -webkit-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
                  -ms-touch-action: none;
                  margin: 0px;
                  padding: 0px;
                  border: 0px;
        }
        :-webkit-full-screen #canvas {
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
        }
        div.gm4html5_div_class
        {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          border: 0px;
        }
        /* START - Login Dialog Box */
        div.gm4html5_login
        {
             padding: 20px;
             position: absolute;
             border: solid 2px #000000;
             background-color: #404040;
             color:#00ff00;
             border-radius: 15px;
             box-shadow: #101010 20px 20px 40px;
        }
        div.gm4html5_cancel_button
        {
             float: right;
        }
        div.gm4html5_login_button
        {
             float: left;
        }
        div.gm4html5_login_header
        {
             text-align: center;
        }
        /* END - Login Dialog Box */
        :-webkit-full-screen {
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
        }
        .centered {
          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gm4html5_div_class centered" id="gm4html5_div_id">
    <img src="html5game/splash.png" id="GM4HTML5_loadingscreen" alt="Loading screen" style="display:none;"/>
        <!-- Create the canvas element the game draws to -->
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="600">
           <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- Run the game code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html5game/SaveTheCity.js?LGLZB=1822663509"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your html markup look like? Also, can you create a fiddle with minimal code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The click doesnt work while transform is setted. I will edit the firs post with more info

Comment: I think that problem is in the canvas element, when we moving it